# How to connect AugurProject's ethrpc to a local testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, testnets, javascript, augur

I have GETH running a test network, and now I'd like to get AugurProject's ETHRPC to connect.  I can't find any documentation on ETHRPC.

Answer (score 5):

By default it connects to the local node running on `8545`

```
// local ethereum node address
localnode: "http://127.0.0.1:8545",
```

[source](https://github.com/AugurProject/ethrpc/blob/master/index.js#L63)

If you read the code, you can see lines like the following and understand how it fetches data.

```
nodes: {
    hosted: HOSTED_NODES.slice(),
    local: null
},
```